# Why can't I connect to Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I had installed VS2008 and VS2008SP1 on my machine a few month ago and today I tried to install TFC again installed VS2008SP1.

But when I try to connect to another machine within domain which my computer belongs to, I 
get this error message:

"TF31002 Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server......"

I should say that I use WinXP sp2 as the OS.

what is the problem?

Comment: It looks like this is resolved - if David's answer was correct, please accept it so he gets credit.

Comment: Thank you for remembering it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is a permissions issue.  You'll need to log on to the Team Foundation Server using whatever account you used to install it, and grant rights to yourself to connect.

Also, here's a link on another forum that may hold answers for you if I'm wrong.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsstart/thread/92cacb2f-d15b-4b8c-bc4d-5692ee5c7571

Answer (score 1):

If TFS and VSTS2008 are installed on the same PC, they won't work properly unless you install them in exactly the right order.

Beyond that, something could be misconfigured - without more information it is impossible to say what. The main problems are usually with permissions. TFS uses a number of log files for the various subsystems it runs, and they can be a big help in tracking down where problems lie.

Answer (score 0):

Are the users in the TFS Licensed Users group?
Our administrator had installed Workgroup Edition and not added everyone to the group. :(